# .k-state-error is not being applied to Kendo Date Picker

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Model validation and k-state-error css class is not being applied to it in case validation fails. what else i can do to add this class to my datepicker

```
  function onChange(e) {
    if (e.date == undefined) {
        var item = $(this).find('.k-picker-wrap');
        $(item).addClass("k-state-error");
       // $(e).css("border-color", "red");
    }
}
```

using this code to add class but it's not working. Perhaps jquery selector is not right

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/validator/overview)) on implementing validator and how they work in KendoUI

Answer (score 0):

From your code seems that you are trying to implement a validation that checks that the date is *required*. Why not implementing it as:

HTML:

```
<input id="date" required/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#date")
        .kendoDatePicker({})
        .kendoValidator({
            validateOnBlur: true,
            messages : {
                required      : "My custom required message"
            }
        });
```